# How to parse and split a text string and save it as an array of arrays

Tags: python, regex, string, text, split

I have the following string, in this example there are 4 rows, but there could be more:

```
  port  device  name           profile  settings
  ====  ======  =============  =======  =================
  1     ttyS1   name1          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none
  2     ttyS2   name2          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none
  3     ttyS3   name3          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none
  4     ttyS4   name4          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none

Press any key to continue...
```

And I need to get data only from the port and name columns, and assign it to an array of arrays, or several arrays.

e.g.

```
['1', 'name1']
['2', 'name2']
['3', 'name3']
['4', 'name4']

or

[['1', 'name1'],['2', 'name2'],['3', 'name3'],['4', 'name4']]
```

Could anyone give me any ideas on how could this be accomplished?

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

txt = """
  port  device  name           profile  settings
  ====  ======  =============  =======  =================
  1     ttyS1   name1          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none
  2     ttyS2   name2          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none
  3     ttyS3   name3          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none
  4     ttyS4   name4          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none

Press any key to continue...
"""

r = re.compile(r"^[^\d]+(\d+)\s*[^\s]+\s*([^\s]+)", flags=re.M)

out = r.findall(txt)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
[('1', 'name1'), ('2', 'name2'), ('3', 'name3'), ('4', 'name4')]
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following. Written and tested in Python3.8, using `findall` function of Python.

```
import re
var="""  port  device  name           profile  settings
====  ======  =============  =======  =================
1     ttyS1   name1          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none
2     ttyS2   name2          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none
3     ttyS3   name3          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none
4     ttyS4   name4          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none"""

re.findall(r'^\s+?(\d+).*?\S+\s+(\S+).*$',var,re.M)
```

Output will be as follows:

```
[('1', 'name1'), ('2', 'name2'), ('3', 'name3'), ('4', 'name4')]
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^\s+?      ##Checking from starting of value spaces occurrences 1 or more optional.
(\d+)      ##Creating 1st capturing group which has continuous digits in it, port number.
.*?\S+\s+  ##using non greedy match to match till non space value(1 or more) followed by 1 or more spaces.
(\S+)      ##Creating 2nd capturing group which has all non space values(names) in it.
.*$        ##Matching rest of the values here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Another users already responted with best solutions but this is my simple solution :D

```
stringOrig = """
  port  device  name           profile  settings
  ====  ======  =============  =======  =================
  1     ttyS1   name1          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none
  2     ttyS2   name2          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none
  3     ttyS3   name3          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none
  4     ttyS4   name4          cas      9600 8N1 ssh none

Press any key to continue...
"""

stringLines = stringOrig.split("\n")
linesContent = stringLines[3:-3]
lineValues = list(
  map(lambda l: 
      list(
        filter(lambda x : x != "", l.split(" "))
      )[0:3:2]
      , linesContent
  )
)
print(lineValues)
```